# Can you add specs to a batch file that would collect user ID and date run of the person who uses it?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that I created to run an installation of a tool on a users computer.  I want to be able to track the users running it, as well as the time they ran it.  Can you write specs in the actual file itself log would log a users computer ID and time stamp?

Comment: You can add commands that output the required info and redirect it to a file.

Comment: What are the commands?

Comment: `whoami` and `time /T`

Answer (score 1):

`%DATE%`, `%TIME%`, `%USERDOMAIN%`, and `%USERNAME%` are all automatic variables you can use.

Something similar to `echo|set/p="%DATE% %TIME% - %USERDOMAIN% - %USERNAME%" && echo; >> log.txt` would accomplish what you want.

I like using `echo|set/p=""` because quoted strings are less likely to cause problems, like if `%USERNAME%` or `%USERDOMAIN%` contains a character that causes cmd to think the echo command is over before it's supposed to be. `&& echo;` creates a linebreak.

Comment: `set/p=` is completely unnecessary.  a simple `(echo "%DATE% %TIME% - %USERDOMAIN% - %USERNAME%")>>logfile` would suffice. Oh, and since you are unaware. Soliciting votes/answer acceptance is not allowed on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the requirement into the first line and ensure you exit before the logging

```
@echo off &Title "%~0" &echo Run %date%%time% by %userprofile%>>"%~0"

rem Your main task goes here

exit /b

Logging starts here

Run 2021-12-23 1:12:02.25 by C:\Users\K
```

Comment: For what reason would you want to log to the batch file itself? You'll have a permanently growing batch-file which is really not what you want to achieve.